# A good way to use native UI functions for Mobile Website.

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, mobile

I am building a site, I have the back-end all sorted, however, I would like to use a `Responsive`and inbuilt `UI` for android and `I`devices.. so for example the native scroll wheel on `i` phones and the quite similar on android. Is there a small plugin (preferably jquery) that can accomplish this? I think mobile is a bit over kill for this project. The exact elements that I would like styled and thus, respond natively are `<select>`'s and maybe checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). For example, according to the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html) for select menus:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = true;
    });
```

> When the select button is clicked, the native select menu picker for
>   the OS will open. When a value is selected in the menu, the custom
>   select button is updated to match the new selection.

Additionally, see the [iOS](https://github.com/taitems/iOS-Inspired-jQuery-Mobile-Theme) and [Android](https://github.com/jjoe64/jquery-mobile-android-theme) inspired themes for jQuery mobile.